# How to avoid jquery initialize object as function more than once

Tags: jquery

I initialize an object as smartphoto like below

```
$(".js_smartphoto").SmartPhoto();
```

If user click paging button, then the code will loop inside

through all list and assign then function again. Right now the object already assigned will be assigned again, so the smartphoto will appear twice.

Is there a way I can check that the $(".js_smartphoto") is already assign with SmartPhoto()? so it can avoid to duplicate assignment. 
maybe code liek this?

```
if($(".js_smartphoto").SmartPhoto() == false)
{
   $(".js_smartphoto").SmartPhoto();
}
```

or another way maybe I can destroy the function first, then initialize again.
like this?

```
$(".js_smartphoto").SmartPhoto().destroy();
$(".js_smartphoto").SmartPhoto();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it shows up in the [SmartPhoto documentation](https://appleple.github.io/SmartPhoto/doc.html#methods), you initialize the SmartPhoto image viewer like this:

```
var mySmartPhoto = new SmartPhoto(".js-smartPhoto");
```

Also, as you can see per documentation, there is no destroy method.
What you could do in your case:

```
// the top of the page
var mySmartPhoto = new SmartPhoto(".js-smartPhoto");

// ... the rest of the code/page

if (typeof mySmartPhoto === 'object') {
    // SmartPhoto was already initialized
}
```